Initial pic or frame is not flipped
In phaser 3 I have the animation below
BaseScene.ball = this.add
  .sprite(0, 0, 'ball1')
  .setOrigin(0.5)
  .setDepth(1);

createBallRotationAnimation(){

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'ball',
      frames: [
        { key: 'ball1' },
        { key: 'ball2' },
        { key: 'ball3' },
        { key: 'ball4' },
        { key: 'ball5' }
      ],
      frameRate: 10, 
      repeat: -1 
    });

    this.ballRotationAnimation = 'ball';

  }

First frame or pic of the animation is not flipped below is my code for flipping then playing
BaseScene.ball.flipX = targetObject.info.index % 2 === 0;   


BaseScene.ball.play(this.ballRotationAnimation);

//stopping the animation
BaseScene.ball.stop();




BaseScene.ball.anims.setCurrentFrame(
BaseScene.ball.anims.currentAnim
.frames[0]);


Your question is not clear, and the added Code, doesn't clear anything up. Check out these articles to improve your questions. btw.: Writing better Questions and accepting answers on your questions, might help motivate people to answer questions.

You can use BaseScene.ball.setFlipX(true); to flip the ball, and BaseScene.ball.setFlipX(false); to unflip the ball
